# Hadoop MapReduce program Error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop2

I have the following error in my first wordcount MapReduce program :

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    cat: `/home/Kumar/DEV/Eclipse/eclipse/Workspace/MyFirstMapReduce/Files/input/': No such file or directory
```

**OS & Hadoop versions**

```
CentOS
Release 6.6 (Final)
Kernel Linux 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64
GNOME 2.28.2

Hadoop 2.6.0 64bit version
```

**Bashrc  configuration**

```
export JAVA_HOME ="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0"
export PATH =$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

export HADOOP_INSTALL="/home/Kumar/DEV/HDS/hadoop"
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin  
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin  
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL  
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL  
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL  
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
```

**Running Daemons**

```
3763 SecondaryNameNode
4406 ResourceManager
22264 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
17736 Jps
30584 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
4697 NodeManager
3611 DataNode
4059 NameNode
```

I copied the WordCount Program from below Apache site and followed the steps as given in this [tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html). When i compiled the WordCount.java , it created 3 class files :

```
hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main /home/Kumar/DEV/Eclipse/eclipse/Workspace/MyFirstMapReduce/src/WordCount.java 

WordCount.class
WordCount$IntSumReducer.class
WordCount$TokenizerMapper.class
```

When I run the HDFS command, it is throwing below warning message and File or Directory Not found message even though the file & director are exist

```
hdfs dfs -cat /home/Kumar/DEV/Eclipse/eclipse/Workspace/MyFirstMapReduce/Files/input/file1

WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
cat: `/home/Kumar/DEV/Eclipse/eclipse/Workspace/MyFirstMapReduce/Files/input/file1': No such file or directory


hdfs dfs -cat /home/Kumar/DEV/Eclipse/eclipse/Workspace/MyFirstMapReduce/Files/input/

WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
cat: `/home/Kumar/DEV/Eclipse/eclipse/Workspace/MyFirstMapReduce/Files/input/': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. File you are trying to use is on Local Linux filesystem not on HDFS.
   So use can use simple command like :

   `cat /home/Kumar/DEV/Eclipse/eclipse/Workspace/MyFirstMapReduce/Files/input/file1`

If your MapReduce program expects the input file on HDFS , then put the same file on HDFS and HDFS path in job . you can use this command to put file on hdfs:

`hadoop fs -put <input-file-path-on-linux> <path-on-hdfs>`

Tutorial you are referring uses old APIs of Mapreduce. You can look the same tutorial for current Hadoop version here : http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep for helping me to understand the problem.  I have configured core-site.xml like below.core-site.xml:
<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>fs.default.name</name>
         <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
     </property>
</configuration>                                                                            so how to find the HDFS path to move my input file hadoop fs -put <input-file-path-on-linux> <path-on-hdfs>.

Comment: I have created directory using  hadoop fs -mkdir  and moved my file. Thanks Pradeep.

Answer (score 0):

The first message is just a warning and is not troublesome.

The second message occurs because `hadoop -fs` will look on hdfs, not on your local filesystem. You may want to check if your files exist with [`ls`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.html#ls).